# How to draw a curved street by TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm interested in drawing a curved street with TikZ. The resulting street should look like this:[image]

At the moment I tried to solve my problem by using a bezier curve. But the results do not satisfy. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz,fullpage}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [thin] (0,-3) -- (0,2);
\draw [thin] (0,4) -- (0,5);
\draw [thin] (2,-3) -- (2,5);
\draw [thin,dashed] (1,-3) -- (1,5);

\draw (-6,-2) .. controls (-4,5) and (-1,3.8) .. (0,4);
\draw (-4,-2) .. controls (-2,3) and (-1,1.8) .. (0,2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

So is there a solution by TikZ maybe for combining simple two points by a curved line?

Thanks for your help!

Greets!

Comment: The hobby package may help.

Comment: You're loading `tikz` twice. Do you need `fullpage` for the example to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use `double` line:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[double =white,double distance=1cm,line width=1mm] (0,-4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0)
                                                            to[out=180, in=90, looseness=2] (-4,-4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[double =black,double distance=1.1cm] (0,-4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0)
                                                            to[out=180, in=90, looseness=2] (-4,-4);
    \draw[white,line width=1mm, loosely dashed] (0,-4) -- (0,4) ;
    \draw[white,line width=1mm, loosely dashed] (-0.4,0) to[out=180, in=90, looseness=2] (-4,-4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, I didn't know about `double distance`. But now I do :D

Comment: Very nice solution, thank you both very much.

Answer (score 11):

You can use a `preaction` to draw a very thick black line before a white line, or even combine it with a `postaction` to draw black, white, black from the outside in. It's not perfect, as you have to think about the order in that you're drawing, but you can remedy that by using layers via `\pgfdeclarelayer{<name>}` and `\pgfsetlayers{<layer list>}`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[preaction={draw, line width=1cm, black}, white, line width=1mm] (0,-4) -- (0,4);
    \draw[preaction={draw, line width=1cm, black}, white, line width=1mm] (-0.4,0) to[out=180, in=90, looseness=2] (-4,-4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
[   road/.style={
    preaction={draw, line width=10mm, black}, 
    white, line width=8mm, 
    postaction={draw, line width=1mm, black, loosely dashed}}   
]
    \draw[road] (0,-4) -- (0,4);
    \draw[road] (-0.4,0) to[out=180, in=90, looseness=2] (-4,-4);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

So this is my final result:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[double=white,double distance=2cm,ultra thick] (0,-4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0) to[out=180, in=90, looseness=2] (-4,-4);
\draw[thick,dashed] (-1,0) to[out=180, in=90, looseness=2] (-4,-4);
\draw[thick,dashed] (0,-4) -- (0,4);
\node (CAR1) at (-3.5,-3.2) [rectangle,draw,thick,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.9cm] {};
\node (CAR2) at (-1.7,-0.5) [rectangle,draw,thick,minimum width=0.5cm,minimum height=0.9cm,rotate=90] {};

\node (T1) at (-3.5,-3.1) [regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,fill=black,minimum height=0.4cm] {};
\node (T2) at (-1.5,-0.5) [regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,fill=black,minimum height=0.4cm,rotate=30] {};

\draw[thick,blue] (-1,-0.5) to[out=180, in=90, looseness=2] (-3.5,-2.8);
\draw[thick,red] (-3.5,-2.8) -- (-2.1,-0.5);

\draw[thick,dotted] (-3.5,-2.8) -| (-2.1,-0.5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But how can I remove these lines(?):

[image]

Comment: It is a viewer artefact. If you zoom those lines won't appear.